# Elasticsearch shallow partial update

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update.html) appears to support two modes of updating:

1. fully replace existing document with new one
2. partially update existing document, recursively merging objects

I want to do a partial update, but do a shallow merge instead of deep merge. This means, if there are any fields that contain objects, I want to fully replace those objects. But if the existing document has top-level fields that I haven't specified in the update, I want those to be preserved.

To illustrate, if I have the following document in the database:

```json
{
  "manual_price": 123.0
  "price": 100.0,
  "feed_fields": {
    "name": "Mango"
    "item_group_id": "123"
  }
}
```

And I send an update with the following data:

```json
{
  "doc": {
    "price": 110.0,
    "feed_fields": {
      "name": "Mango Fresh"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would like the resulting document to be:

```json
{
  "manual_price": 123.0,
  "price": 110.0,
  "feed_fields": {
    "name": "Mango Fresh"
  }
}
```

By default, the `feed_fields` is deep-merged, so the `item_group_id` remains instead of getting erased.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, and I found 2 options, neither of them perfect.

1. You can use the script to set the `feed_fields` value:

```json
{
  "script" : {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.feed_fields = params.feed_fields",
    "params" : {
      "feed_fields": { "name": "Mango Fresh" }
    }
  }
}
```

The downside to this is then you have to set the rest of the fields in the script as well, which is annoying.

2. You can make 2 updates: first set `feed_fields` to `null`, then set them to their new value. You can do this in a single request by using [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the field to null, which has the same effect as removing it

```
{
  "doc": {
    "price": 110.0,
    "feed_fields": {
      "name": "Mango Fresh",
      "item_group_id": null
    }
  }
}
```

The other solution is to do a scripted update and call `ctx._source.feed_fields.remove('item_group_id')` in the script.

Comment: Interesting that setting to `null` has the same effect. The problem is, I don't know which fields I should nullify, I would have to retrieve the current list of sub-fields from index properties, which seems hacky. I also saw I can remove it via a script, but how to then immediately set it with the new value? I want to eliminate the chance of a parallel request retrieving the document with `feed_fields` removed.

Comment: How many fields can `feed_fields` contain?

Comment: Unspecified amount. Which fields are stored there depends on our customers, we're essentially storing fields from an XML they send us. So, different customers will have different fields (and we're using a separate ES index per customer).

Comment: I tried writing `null` values in `feed_fields`, but that doesn't seem to remove the field, it still gets written into the document, just with the `null` value. This is not ideal, I would prefer being able to remove it from the document.